# How can I enable installation of an application to overwrite existing installation, rather than require that I uninstall the original?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, deployment, windows-installer, setup-project

I'm using the Setup and Deployment project in Visual Studio 2010 to create an .msi installer. I can install the application fine on a clean machine, but if I need to reinstall the app, e.g. if there are updates, resolved bugs or new features, it means that I have to uninstall first and then re-install. I'd like to be able to just install over the existing installation without having to uninstall first.

Is this possible? If so, what do I need to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer to these pages for an answer;

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/seykw6dt (See the RemovePreviousVersions property)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y63fxdw6 (Explanation of the RemovePreviousVersions property)

You should probably also increase the version number of your changed files.